# How to access different database for different subbranch stores in java web?

Tags: java, hibernate, e-commerce, multiple-databases

I am trying to implement a small ecommerce website. And some requirements are

- There are many branch stores. Each store can have different products
- when using my website, people first choose store, then browse products in store chose
- Different branch store want to have their customize web page template

So My thought is

1. Specify separately database for each branch store(fix the 1st and 2nd requirements), we use url to decide which database to query

   As product's structure is same, all the databases have same schema(Table definition). When maintaining by CMS, each store insert differnt product content into different database. And after people choose store(i.e. www.my.com/1102, which means 1102 branch store is chosen), my server can query data all from corresponding database.

   Can this be done in java web development? If yes, how and any disadvantage? If no, how to solve such requirement? Thanks.

   Any comments is appreciated.

Comment: Search for multi tenancy on Google you will find solution for it...